# Assign variable to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

First, I am not too verse with JavaScript. I would like to build a HTML table TD elements with content dynamically using JavaScript. Here is my code that is not working properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changed(num){
    a1=num;
    a2=num+1;
    a3=num+2;

    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
       document.getElementById("boxA"+i).innerHTML=eval('a'+i);
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="box" onChange="changed(this.value);">

<table width="400" border="10" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <td id="boxA1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="boxA2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="boxA3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If I entered the value 1 in the input field, the following values should be 1, 2, 3

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator will always perform concatenation when a `String` is given to it, which the `value` of an `<input>` will always be:

```
console.log('1' + 1);
// '11'

console.log(1 + '1');
// '11'
```

You'll have to convert the `value` to a `Number` to perform addition:

```
<... onChange="changed(parseFloat(this.value));">
```

---

You should also consider using an `Array` or `Object` to collect related values, especially those you need to iterate over:

```
function changed(num){
    var a = {
        1: num,
        2: num + 1,
        3: num + 2
    };

    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
       document.getElementById("boxA"+i).innerHTML = a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 surprisingly the value of an input of type number is also a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach ....

```
function changed(n){

  n = parseInt(n); // convert to integer
  if (!n) { return; } // end execution if not found (if not a number)

  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

    // Since there is no HTML, textContent is better
    // eval is not needed (people often say eval is evil) ;)
    // using the i to increment
    document.getElementById('boxA' + i).textContent = n + i -1;
  }
}
```

Good luck
:)